# Testing an optional file upload in Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, file-upload, flask-wtforms

I have a form in a Flask app that has an optional file upload that I would like to unit test.  The form looks like this:

```py
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    image_file = FileField('Upload a profile image if you want')
```

I then handle POST requests with this:

```py
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data)
        if request.files['image_file']:
            # Do something with the file if the user uploaded one...
        return redirect('index')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

This code works when I test it out in the browser for both cases when the user uploads an image or does not upload an image.  I can also unit test it to cover the case where a user uploads a photo:

```py
class TestRegistration(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_register(self):
        file = Path('foo.jpeg')
        PIL.Image.new('1', (256, 256)).save(file)
        data = {'username': 'Alice', 'image_file': file.open('rb')}
        
        with self.app.test_client():
            response = self.client.post('/register', data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However I am having difficulty writing a unit test to handle the case when a user does not upload an image.  If I omit `'image_file'` in `data` the form does not validate.  Setting `data['image_file'] = ''` also does not work.  I have also tried creating an empty file with `file.touch()` and then calling `'image_file': file.open('rb')`, but this seems to have the effect of uploading an empty file rather than sending the form without a file upload.

How do I test the behavior of sending the form without the file upload?

Comment: I believe that the problem is not in the unit test, but in the implementation. If you see the [WTForm FileField documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FileField), you can see that there is a validation if there is data (file content). You may have to handle with empty content and bypass the file field form flow.